# Check value of a dynamic id in firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

I'm fairly new to Firebase, and I'm writing rules for my database.
I have something like this :

```
"messages" : {
  "generatedId1" : {
    "status" : "waiting"
    "sender" : "uid"
  },
  "generatedId2" : {
    "status" : "send"
    "sender" : "uid2"
  }
 }
```

This is just an example and not the actual database.

What I want is to set rules so that the client can request all messages that has the status "waiting", but can't request messages with status "send".
The problem is that I don't know how to set a rules on the status, when I'm on the messages level.

I have something like this :

```
"messages" : {
  ".read": "(auth != null && data.child($generated).child('status').val() === 'WAITING')"
}
```

The problem here is that I can't reach the status. $generated obviously doesn't work and I didn't find anything to access all child.

Side note, I already think about separating the lists (one list for messages in waiting and one for message in send), but it's really not optimum in my case, I need an another solution (if it exists)

If you have it, it would be welcome !

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [query-based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules). In your case the rule would look something like this:

```
"messages" : {
  ".read": "auth != null && 
           query.orderByChild == 'status' &&
           query.equalTo == 'waiting'" 
}
```

Just remember you will have to use the same query to read your data.

Comment: I'll try that and come back to you, probably tomorrow! But it looks good, I just need to check if it's working for all the use-cases.
It should work even if status is not the direct child of messages right ?

Comment: @RomainHuber If i have read the docs correctly thats true. But I havent used it myself so far so I can be mistaken.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like its not working. Status isn't a child of messages, I don't think there is a solution other than changing the structure of my database

Comment: Acually it is checking for the child status of a single message, not the entire messages array. (As you can see from the example in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html)) But maybe its failing because of the equalTo condition.

Comment: Can you perhaps add the code you used to try to read messages to your question?

Comment: My team is using this request : (swift version). Got a permission denied everytime.

`self.databaseReference.child("messages")
            .queryOrdered(byChild: "status")
            .queryEqual(toValue: "waiting")`

Comment: Is the value in you database WAITING or is it waiting? Because firebase is case-sensitve so those two are actually different.

Comment: It's "WAITING" in my datebase, but I change it to "waiting" to match my example.

Comment: Uh, but it seems that it's working! Maybe I wrote "waiting" instead of "WAITING" yesterday. Thank you !